# AngularJS, pass params to another controller

Tags: angularjs

a quick question.

I have some objects in an array and I must generate some button.

```
[{
title: "Uno",
url: "http://xxx.json"
},
title: "Due",
url: "http://xxx.json"
}]
```

Everything works fine with ng-repeat

```
<button ng-repeat="genre in home.genres.genres" ui-sref="genre" class="button button-block button-light">{{genre.title}}</button>
```

Now I have a problem: when the user click a button must go the a new view, genre, but in the new view I must make an $http call to the related url. How can I pass the url in the array item to the new controller?

Comment: have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not very far from the solution; that is assuming that you are using `ngRoute`.

By modifying the definition of your button to include a function call via `ng-click(...)`, you can get the desired result.

```
<button ng-click="loadOtherController(genre.url)" ng-repeat="genre in home.genres.genres" ui-sref="genre" class="button button-block button-light">{{genre.title}}</button>
```

Now in your controller that's loading the buttons, you need to define the `loadOtherController(...)` function.

```
$scope.loadOtherController = function(targetURL) {
   $location.url(targetURL);
}
```

Also, instead of passing fully qualified urls, just pass the name. So `http:\\something-great.json` becomes `something-great`.

In the other controller, you then use `$routeParams`, to get the targetURL, which you can then pass to `$http` once you have modified the url to include the `.json` extension.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using ui-router? If so, ui-sref will only work on `<a>` elements.

Check out the ui-sref section of the documentation
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

There's a few changes to be done here.

You need to specify parameters within your target states url.
For example:

```
url:"genre/{mygenre}"
```

This will add the 'mygenre' parameter to that state

*I would then use a word other than genre in your ng-repeat. You are using a view called genre then using repeated items also called genre. It could cause unexpected bugs and is generally just confusing. In this example I've named it genreItem.*

Then pass your parameter through your ui-sref tag, for example

```
ui-sref="genre({mygenre:genreItem})"
```

then inside the controller for the target state, inject $stateParams which then allows you to use the parameters specified

```
app.controller("genreController", function($scope, $stateParams){
   alert( $stateParams.mygenre )
});
```

**if** you want to use your button, inject $state and create a function that calls $state.go("genre", params), then bind that function to ng-click on the button.

Comment: The button works with Ionic: the problem is that I don't have a params, I have an "url string" to pass...

Comment: You should specify every framework you are using inside your question. You include the param inside the url string.